# pyaudio save multiple .WAV file with nonblocking

Tags: callback, wav, nonblocking, pyaudio

Updates:
Now I found out that we can paste some code in the callback function and ended up more questions:

1. When will be call and stop the callback functions? when we open and close the stream?
2. The callback function can return the stream data(audio_data from the code). As we did not call the function, the pyaudio do it internally I believe. How do I get the return stream data from callback?

```py
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np
import npstreams
import time


CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

channel_1_frames = []
channel_2_frames = []
fulldata = np.array([])

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
    global b,a,fulldata #global variables for filter coefficients and array
    
    audio_data = np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.int16)
   
    channel_1 = audio_data[0::CHANNELS]
    channel_2 = audio_data[1::CHANNELS]
    data1 = channel_1.tostring()
    data2 = channel_2.tostring()
    channel_1_frames.append(data1)
    channel_2_frames.append(data2)
    wf1 = wave.open('Channel_1.wav', 'wb')
    wf2 = wave.open('Channel_2.wav', 'wb')
    wf1.setnchannels(1)
    wf2.setnchannels(1)
    wf1.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf2.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf1.setframerate(RATE)
    wf2.setframerate(RATE)
    wf1.writeframes(b''.join(channel_1_frames))
    wf2.writeframes(b''.join(channel_2_frames))
    wf1.close()
    wf2.close()
    
    return (audio_data, pyaudio.paContinue)


stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                #frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(10)
    stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

audio.terminate()
```

=============================================

I am trying to record multiple channels into multiple .WAV file.
I can do that with stream.read() and numpy array to separate into different array, and save to .WAV file

```py
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

channel_1_frames = []
channel_2_frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    # convert string to numpy array
    data_array = np.frombuffer(data, dtype='int16')
    # select channel
    channel_1 = data_array[0::CHANNELS]
    channel_2 = data_array[1::CHANNELS]
    # convert numpy array to string 
    data1 = channel_1.tostring()
    data2 = channel_2.tostring()
    channel_1_frames.append(data1)
    channel_2_frames.append(data2)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
```

However, from the module documentation, https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#class-stream, it said stream.read() and stream.write() should not be used for non-blocking.

And I found a good non-blocking pyaudio example from Github: https://gist.github.com/sloria/5693955
Which did not use stream.read().

I am not sure if I can read and turn steam numpy array without stream.read()
So is it still possible to export the stream in to different .WAV? and make it non blocking?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I learn more in coding, I found the answers.

A1: The callback function run and stop with the stream.

```py
######open stream with out starting automatically
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=format,
channels=2,
rate=44100,
input=True,
frames_per_buffer=44100,
stream_callback=self.get_callback(),
start=False)

######start,stop stream
stream.start_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
```

A2: To capture data in real time, we can use queue

```py
self.recorded_frames = queue.Queue()
    def get_callback(self):
        def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
            self.recorded_frames.put(np.frombuffer(in_data, dtype=np.int16))
            return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue
        return callback
```